# How to exclude records based on second table (using JOIN)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I think this is simple, but not so today...

I have two tables The first has a column with data from the second.

```
T1 has Column1 value = "Created"
T2 has Column1 Value = "Created" and Column2 Value = "OPEN"
```

So the idea is to return every row from table 1 where column 2 of table 2 = "OPEN"

This si the current SELECT

```
SELECT tblCustIncidents.IncidentID, tblCustIncidents.EntryDateTime, tblCustIncidents.Title, tblCustIncidents.StatusType, tblCustIncidents.Summary, tblMaintStatusTypes.StatusDescr
FROM tblCustIncidents LEFT JOIN
     tblMaintStatusTypes
     ON tblCustIncidents.StatusType = tblMaintStatusTypes.StatusType;
```

I thought I could just use WHERE but I am not clear on the location of the WHERE or even if it will work... I've been looking more than a little while. I'll keep looking and hope someone can point me tot he right method/answer/post etc. Thanks.

In the screenshot of the returned data the last column is in both tables. The second table has a column indictaing if the item is open or closed. SO I would want all records in the snippet NOT to appear... I have tried this Select statement...

```
SELECT tblCustIncidents.IncidentID, tblCustIncidents.EntryDateTime, tblCustIncidents.Title, tblCustIncidents.StatusType, tblCustIncidents.Summary, tblMaintStatusTypes.StatusDescr
FROM tblCustIncidents LEFT JOIN tblMaintStatusTypes ON tblCustIncidents.StatusType = tblMaintStatusTypes.StatusType
WHERE tblMaintStatusTypes.OpenOrClosedType = 'Open';
```

[image]

OK I figured out access is picky... so I have tried this...

```
    SELECT tblCustIncidents.IncidentID, 
        tblCustIncidents.EntryDateTime, 
        tblCustIncidents.Title, 
        tblCustIncidents.StatusType, 
        tblCustIncidents.Summary, 
        tblMaintStatusTypes.StatusDescr
    FROM tblCustIncidents 
    inner join (SELECT tblCustIncidents.IncidentID, 
        tblCustIncidents.EntryDateTime, 
        tblCustIncidents.Title, 
        tblCustIncidents.StatusType, 
        tblCustIncidents.Summary, 
        tblMaintStatusTypes.StatusDescr
    FROM tblCustIncidents)
    ON (tblCustIncidents.StatusType = tblMaintStatusTypes.StatusType AND tblMaintStatusTypes.OpenOrClosedType = 'Open');
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: if you do Left Join you will also get the rows from table1 where column2 value is not 'open'. LEFT join means select everything from left table regardless of the matching value from right table found or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT t1.*
    FROM table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.Column1=t2.Column1
    WHERE t2.column2='OPEN'
```

Comment: SELECT tblCustIncidents.IncidentID, tblCustIncidents.EntryDateTime, tblCustIncidents.Title, tblCustIncidents.StatusType, tblCustIncidents.Summary, tblMaintStatusTypes.StatusDescr
FROM tblCustIncidents LEFT JOIN tblMaintStatusTypes ON tblCustIncidents.StatusType = tblMaintStatusTypes.StatusType
WHERE tblMaintStatusTypes.OpenOrClosedType = 'Open';

Comment: you are doing the LEFT JOIN and i have mentioned to do the regular JOIN. (INNER JOIN where INNER word is optional)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query you just need to add clause to the `join` and than change `join` from `left` to `inner`, otherwise you will still get all rows from table 1.

```
SELECT tblCustIncidents.IncidentID
       ,tblCustIncidents.EntryDateTime
       ,tblCustIncidents.Title
       ,tblCustIncidents.StatusType
       ,tblCustIncidents.Summary
       ,tblMaintStatusTypes.StatusDescr
    FROM tblCustIncidents
    INNER JOIN tblMaintStatusTypes
        ON tblCustIncidents.StatusType = tblMaintStatusTypes.StatusType
    WHERE tblMaintStatusTypes.Column2 = 'OPEN'
```

Comment: OK, didn't think to mention this is in access. I am now getting an error "Join expression not supported" when I do this...SELECT tblCustIncidents.IncidentID, 
            tblCustIncidents.EntryDateTime, 
            tblCustIncidents.Title, 
            tblCustIncidents.StatusType, 
            tblCustIncidents.Summary, 
            tblMaintStatusTypes.StatusDescr
    FROM (tblCustIncidents INNER JOIN tblMaintStatusTypes ON tblCustIncidents.StatusType = tblMaintStatusTypes.StatusType AND tblMaintStatusTypes.OpenOrClosedType = 'Open');

Comment: in that case just change it to `WHERE` clause. And change `JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` here is full documentation on [tag:ms-access] `INNER JOIN` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208854(v=office.12).aspx